# Razor Pages Net Core auto reload partial view on set frequency

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am still trying to get to grips with Razor Pages for Net Core and seem to be a bit stuck on this. I have my Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<input type="hidden" name="hdnPageSelector" id="hdnIndexPage" />

<div class="text-center">
    <p>Welcome to</p>
    <h1 class="display-4">"My Web App"</h1>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <partial name="IndexPartials/_Navigation" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <partial name="IndexPartials/_Body" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div id="refreshMembers" class="form-group col-md-2">
        <partial name="IndexPartials/_Members" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the last **div** has an `id="refreshMembers"`.
The partial view (_Members) that is loaded there looks like this:

```
@model IndexModel
    
<label>Members</label>
<br />

@{
    foreach (ApplicationUser user in Model.AppUsersList)
    {
        if (user.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            <label>@user.FirstName @user.LastName </label>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        }
        else
        {
            <label>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</label>
        }
    }
}
```

Within the controller I have a property called:

```
public IList<ApplicationUser> AppUsersList { get; set; }
```

And this is populated on `OnGetAsync()` as follows:

```
AppUsersList = _userManager.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Where(y => y.UserName != currentUser.UserName).ToList();
```

This is fine, the page loads with the partial view populated as expected. I now want the partial to refresh every 5 seconds so I have put this piece of Javascript/JQuery in place:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {

        $("#refreshMembers").load("/Index?handler=RefreshMembers");

    }, 5000);
});
```

with the following method setup:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetRefreshMembers()
{
    var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    AppUsersList = _userManager.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Where(y => y.UserName != currentUser.UserName).ToList();

    return new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "_Members",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<List<ApplicationUser>>(ViewData, AppUsersList)
    };

}
```

However the partial view doesn't get refreshed. If I put a breakpoint within this method I can see it is being hit every 5 seconds, despite Devtools stating there is an error on each attempt:

[image]

In a nut shell, I just can't seem to get my partial view to be reloaded every 5 seconds. It feels like I am close but just missing something and don't know what that is.

Comment: there is some error on the server, you need to look into the *Output* window to see the detailed exception.

Comment: Thank you.... I had missed all the info I needed in the output window! lol Long weekend! I will post the fix below!

Answer (score 0):

Having been reminded to check the Output window in VS a bit better, I found the cause of my problems... Well two things actually. This is the corrected method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetRefreshMembers()
{
    var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    AppUsersList = _userManager.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).Where(y => y.UserName != currentUser.UserName).ToList();

    return new PartialViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "IndexPartials/_Members",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IndexModel>(ViewData, this)
    };
}
```

Where...

1. I didn't include the folder that the partial lives in when naming it on the PartialViewResult
2. I need to return the entire IndexModel object - having updated the AppUserList property, and not just the list of AppUsers.